# Error at the base system level of ubuntu server installation

Tags: server, files

I tried installing ubuntu server alongside my windows 7 from a usb drive. After the partitioner level, the installation gives this: 
warning: file:///cmrom/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb was corrupted. 
Should I download another server file? Or is there another way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like it is corrupted, so yes, try downloading again.

Comment: and make sure the checksum matches the published one after downloading it!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would check the MD5SUM of the .iso you downloaded, to make sure that isn't corrupted. Here is a link to a tool to check the MD5SUM on Windows: http://www.georgejopling.co.uk/md5check/md5check.html and here is a link to the MD5SUMs of the current .iso's to compare against: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/MD5SUMS. If the MD5SUMs don't match, redownload your iso, because that is the problem.

If everything looks gravy, I'd just try and recreate the flash drive installer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the warning says that the coreutils package was corrupted, you should probably download a new iso image of Ubuntu. But one thing that you should try before downloading a new iso image, is to check the checksum of the file you have with ou now, to ensure that it is not corrupted-

Assuming that you are using ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso
the `SHA1 checksum` is:
`f44b5f8fc9d56e8fd7599e9c1677a640dda85eda`
and the `MD5 checksum` is:
`f2e921788d35bbdf0336d05d228136eb`

Courtesy:http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/MD5SUMS and 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/SHA1SUMS